# Redux Selectors in Mithril

Tags: redux, mithril.js

I've been tasked with implementing selectors in our redux application.  Everything I'm reading online about redux selectors talks about React and how you can replace what is in mapStateToProps with a selector.  What is the equivalent/where would i do this in a mithril app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the equivalent/where would i do this in a mithril app?

Firstly, you don't need an equivalent, you can just use the exact same selectors that you would in a React application.

## Where to call selectors?

You can call the selectors wherever you want, but I recommend calling them as close to where the data is used as possible. Don't call selectors in a component high up in the component hierarchy only to pass the data down via several components before they end up in a component that actually uses the data – unless you have a good reason to do so.

For most cases you can call the selectors inside a `view`-function, although you might come across cases where you need to call selectors in other [lifecycle methods](https://mithril.js.org/lifecycle-methods.html) as well. In some applications you might also want to use selectors in [`m.render`](https://mithril.js.org/render.html) as well.

A couple of examples off the top of my head:

1. Inside the `view` function when creating DOM-elements

   ```js
   var LoggedinUserDetails = {
       view: function () {
           return m('', [
               m('', getLoggedinUserName(store.getState())), // getLoggedinUserName is a selector
               m('img', { src: getLoggedinUserImageUrl(store.getState()) }) // getLoggedinUserImageUrl is a selector
           ])
       }
   }
   ```
2. Inside the `view` function when creating Mithril components

   ```js
   var UserDetails = {
       view: function (attrs) {
           return m('', [
               m('', attrs.user.name),
               m('img', { src: attrs.user.imageUrl })
           ])
       }
   }

       ...
       m(UserDetails, { user: getLoggedInUserDetails(store.getState()) }) // getLoggedInUserDetails is a selector
   ```
3. Inside `m.render`

   In this example, we have a game that requires us to re-render the whole page after any change.

   ```js
   function onStateChange() {
       var state = store.getState();

       m.render(document.body, m(Game, {
           map: getMap(state),
           players: getPlayers(state),
           visibleArea: getVisibleArea(state)
       }));
   }

   // Receiving partial state updates from server via websockets
   websocket.on('update-map', function (map) {
       store.dispatch({ type: 'update-map', payload: map });
   });

   websocket.on('update-players', function (players) {
       store.dispatch({ type: 'update-players', payload: players });
   });

   // Changing state based on user input
   window.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
       switch (event.key) {
           case 'Enter':
               store.dispatch({ type: 'move-visible-area-to-next-player' });
               break;
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks Arne.  Is there a reason you are passing in the state to the selectors as a parameter instead of calling store.getState() within the selector itself?  Does this help with the memoization?

Comment: Apart from the fact that the examples I have seen do it that way, I pass the state into the selectors mainly because then I don't get bi-directional dependencies when placing the selectors in the same file as the reducer, following the [Ducks pattern](https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux#ducks-redux-reducer-bundles). I doubt it matters at all in terms of performance.

Comment: @PaulFabbroni I just re-read your question. It does indeed make it possible to create memoized selectors using e.g. [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect#api).

Comment: Thanks.  So basically it doesn't really matter where you put the call to your selectors.  A selector is a just a function which takes the state and returns a value from it.

Comment: @PaulFabbroni Exactly!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Mithril, but Redux state selectors are independent from React. They are just functions that expect state and return a:

- a slice of state
- or data derived from state

For example, if I my Redux state has an entry named *records* containg a list of models:

```
{
    records: [ ... ],
}
```

I could create a selector returning the length:

```
const numOfRecords = state => state.records.length
```

Or if my state also keeps track of a *sortBy* value:

```
const sortedRecords = state => state.records.sort(sortByFn(state.sortBy))
```

Selectors can be helpful to increase performance and reduce the need for updates. (`reselect` is a great module for this).

They are also great for developing modular pieces of code that depend on data stored in application state but don't really want to know where that data comes from.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I'm actually familiar with all that, the issue I'm having is where to "intercept" the usual action-reducer combo and just use a selector instead.  In React it says to do this in mapStateToProps, but I'm having a hard time figuring out where to do this in Mithril.  e.g. I have a search feature that allows people to search for certain dashboards based on name.  If I use a filter in my reducer, it returns a new state with just the matching dashboards and the other dashboards are lost (even after you wipe out your search) i.e. it's not a true selector

Comment: It's just a reducer returning an altered state.  Even though I used a filter which doesn't mutate the state, the reducer returns a new state (the filtered results).  My current workaround is to set a property of isVisible to true or false on my dashboards, but I'd rather use a selector.

Comment: Not sure why this got an up vote as it didn't answer the question and just described what selectors are...